# Decompiling Assistance w/ Loop

Tags: c, assembly, x86, decompiling

I am reversing some x86 from an old CTF from 2014 and am trying to understand the below code (it has been shortened drastically).  I believe it is performing some sort of while or for loop through a string x number of times where x is the length of the string.

Some Basic Info:

- Intel Syntax
- Function Prototype Given:

  - int main(char*);

My primary confusion lies within the end of .L3 and .L2:

I believe the end of .L3 is storing the register arithmetic in [ebp-12] and then increasing the value of [ebp-8] (I believe this is a pointer to a copy of the char* arg)

```
.L1
    push    ebp    
    mov     ebp, esp
    push    ebx 
    sub     esp, 20 
    mov     DWORD PTR [ebp-12], 0
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR [ebp+8]
    mov     DWORD PTR [ebp-8], eax
    jmp     .L2
.L3
    // Bunch of annoying arithmetic w/ registers
    mov     DWORD PTR [ebp-12], eax     
    add     DWORD PTR [ebp-8], 1        
.L2:
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR [ebp-8]      
    movzx   eax, BYTE PTR [eax]         
    test    al, al                      
    jne     .L3                             
    add     esp, 20
    pop     ebx
    pop     ebp
    ret
```

My loose conversion of this (disregarding much of .L3) is as follows in c:

```
int main(char* arg)
{
    int loc1 = 0;
    char* str = arg;
    for(i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {         //  <=== Pretty Sure
         // .L3 Stuff w/ Assignment to loc1   //  This is incorrect
    }
    return loc1;
}
```

Would someone be willing to explain the incrementation of the [ebp-8], first four lines of .L2, and confirm/deny that during the return the value of eax or loc1 as I called it will return based on the end of .L2?

## EDIT:

The only additional interesting piece of the code has to do with these three lines which show up repeatedly within .L3:

```
    mov    eax, DWORD PTR [ebp-8]
    movzx  eax, BYTE PTR [eax]    
    movsx  eax, al
```

I believe these three lines are de-referencing the pointers address, zero extending the bits and then sign extending the al byte.  In terms of "c" code I believe it is just being used to index each specific char within the array, specifically to use its decimal value for arithmetic.

Comment: There's a StackExchange site for this sort of thing called [Reverse Engineering.SE](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Posted on there as well. Kinda hoping this gets a faster response though.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it appears to be doing "something" with each character in a string. It could be computing a hash code or a CRC, or any one of an infinite number of possible things. Without knowing what the "annoying math" is, it's impossible to say.

A more correct C version of the code would be:

```
int main(char* arg)
{
    char* p = arg;
    int loc1 = 0;
    for (; *p != 0; p++)
    {
        loc1 = do_something_with(*p);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It doesn't return `loc1`, as you stated. The terminating condition is here:

```
movzx   eax, BYTE PTR [eax]         
test    al, al                      
jne     .L3
```

The first instruction zero-extends EAX. So if the AL register is zero, then so is EAX. If the jump isn't taken, then EAX is 0 and that's the value returned by the function.

At least, that's the way it looks to me. But then, what does the function do. If my reading is correct, then the function doesn't actually do anything useful. Unless that "annoying math" includes references to some variables that are at an outer scope.

Comment: In Intel syntax, `movzx   eax, BYTE PTR [eax]` loads and zero-extends the byte pointed to by `eax` into the register `eax`, replacing the pointer's value.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist: Yes, that's correct. So if, after that instruction, the AL register is 0, then all  of EAX is 0. The next instruction `test al,al` will set the Z flag if AL is 0. The jump is taken only when the Z flag is not set. So when the function exits, AL is 0 and therefore EAX is 0.

Comment: @JimMischel Following the `movzx eax, BYTE PTR [eax]` command when will the Z flag not be set?  When it points to a NULL byte therefore it compares NULL byte to NULL byte w/ the `test al,al` instruction below?

Comment: @Kaiser17: What's your question? My point is that the function always returns 0, as I explained above. If you don't agree, please explain how the return value can be anything else.

Comment: @Kaiser17 Jim is right. [`test`](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-manual-325462.pdf) is an instruction that ANDs two registers and sets the P, S and Z register flags according to the result when the register has an odd number of bits set, has the sign bit set or has no bits set respectively. When you AND a value with itself, it is unchanged (`(x & x) == x`), so the `test` instruction is in effect checking `x` alone for parity, sign and zero. And "Z" can only occur if `al` contains the NUL byte.